# How to get the first value from the pd.cut range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows

```
    COLUMN-1    
6   2200        
51  4699        
126 5139        
133 3900      
240 5301
```

I have a used `pd.cut` in a data frame and stored the values in a new column. The data frame now looks like this

```
    COLUMN-1    NEW-COLUMN
6   2200        (2100, 2400]
51  4699        (4500, 4800]
126 5139        (5100, 5400]
133 3900        (3600, 3900]
240 5301        (5100, 5400]
```

But I want only the first element from the range like this

```
    COLUMN-1    BIN
6   2200        2100
51  4699        4500
126 5139        5100
133 3900        3600
240 5301        5100
```

I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried using the `labels` attribute

```
lst = [i for i in range(0, 11481, 300)]
df['NEW-COLUMN'] = pd.cut(crashes_pulaski['COLUMN-1'], 300, labels=lst)
```

but this results in the following error message.

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you have in `lst` are the breaks to divide them. If you have n breaks, you will get n-1 labels. So in this case, you do not specify `300` inside `pd.cut`, because this means the number of breaks. You provide the breaks and use everything up to the last element of the breaks as labels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN-1':[2200,4699,5139,3900,5301]})
df['NEW-COLUMN'] = pd.cut(df['COLUMN-1'],lst,labels=lst[:-1])

   COLUMN-1 NEW-COLUMN
0      2200       2100
1      4699       4500
2      5139       5100
3      3900       3600
4      5301       5100
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` returns a categorical array of intervals. Take the left border of each interval:

```
df['NEW-COLUMN'] = [i.left for i in pd.cut(crashes_pulaski['COLUMN-1'], 300).to_list()]
```